# android, netcat: how to send more than 2048 Byte over UDP

Tags: java, android, udp, transfer, netcat

I'm trying to implement data transfer from a Notebook (Linux) to an Android Device over UDP.

On the notebook I launch:

```
cat /home/me/my/file.txt | nc -u 192.168.150.3 12345
```

Or:

```
nc -u 192.168.150.3 12345 < /home/me/my/file.txt
```

getting same result.

On the Android Device my code is:

```
byte[] msg = new byte[100000];

DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length);
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(portNumber);
s.receive(p);

message = new String(msg, 0, p.getLength());

s.close();
```

If I set a breakpoint on the line with "message =" I can see msg.length = 100000. That's right. But p.getLength() is only 2048. That means only a part of my data is transferred. I mean "message" doesn't contain all data which is in "file.txt". Why does it happen? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

nc does not send the whole file in a single UDP packet, so don't expect to get it in a single call to receive. You must call receive multiple times until everything is complete. Of course, with UDP you get no "end of connection", so you must have some other indicator that you got all data. And, with UDP packets can be silently lost or reordered, so there is no guarantee that you get the file the way you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was my suspicion too. Do you maybe know what does netcat wait for after sending a file over udp?

Comment: @user3137385: netcat just waits for data from the peer. And because there is no end-of-file or connection close in UDP it will wait until you kill it.

Comment: I want to write a script, which has to send every second a file over udp. Is there any possibility to kill that waiting automatically?

Comment: @user3137385: Look at the man page or usage, option -q. And, like I already said, UDP does not guarantee ordered delivery or any delivery at all of the packets, so the received file might be corrupt.

Comment: @user3137385 It also doesn't guarantee you won't receive a packet more than once.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. But UDP is the guideline. I don't have to love it but to accept.